# How i can remove a element inside this

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I want to delete an element which is inside "this"

this=object with a div, which has different content and inside it has an element with the "this_should_removed" class.

I tried to do it in this way, but it failed.

```
$($(this)).find('.this_should_removed').remove();
```

What is the correct way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does `$(this).find('.this_should_removed').remove();` work?

Comment: ```$(this).find('.this_should_removed').remove()``` will do that. you don't have to wrap $(this) twice.

Comment: @holydragon - no it wont remove the element

Comment: @Tamim - yes, that will work :-))

Comment: What's going on here?  "Does A work" No.  "Does A work" Yes.  Both comments above are identical yet one works but the other doesn't?

Comment: To everyone saying `$($(this))` is wrong - it's perfectly valid to wrap a jquery object within `$()` as many times as you like and any actions on that wrapping will work as if it wasn't wrapped.  Example: `$("div").first()[0] === $($($("div").first()))[0]`

Comment: Please provide a complete snippet that demonstrates the problem.  All existing answers incorrectly concentrate on `$($(this))` or just *guess* at the problem.  HAve a read of [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not find any reason for which your code will not work. Though single reference to jQuery is much better.

```
$(this).find('.this_should_removed').remove();
```

Maybe the *this* is not referencing the element you think.

**Demo:**

```js
$('.parent').click(function(e){
  $($(this)).find('.this_should_removed').remove();
});

$('.this_should_removed').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  Some text
  <div class="this_should_removed">
    this_should_removed
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all `$($(this))` is different from `$(this)` so your code isn't working because you are using the wrong object in `$($(this))`, it should be

```
$(this).find('.this_should_removed').remove()
```

But if you check the **[jQuery `.remove()` docs](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)** you can see that you can pass a `selector` to the `remove` method:

> **.remove( [selector ] )**
>
> selector
>   `Type: String`
>
> A selector expression that filters the set of matched elements to be
>   removed.

So your code should be simply:

```
$(this).remove('.this_should_removed');
```

Comment: Can you please tell the reason why `$($(this)).find('.this_should_removed').remove();` don't work?

Comment: @MaheerAli Because  `$($(this)) != $(this)`, btw why would we use `find` if specs provides a better and easier solution?!

Comment: that wont work. like @Tamim "$(this).find('.this_should_removed').remove()" this works for me

Comment: @mikeD Both will work, but if you check my edit I said that you are using the wrong object in `$($(this))` in your code, that's why it won't work.

Comment: First of all `$($(this))` *is* different from `$(this)` but they're both jquery objects and any actions will work on both the same way.  Wrapping a jquery object inside another jquery object is not the issue here.

Comment: Secondly, just because you *can* pass a selector to `.remove()` doesn't mean you have to and `$(parent).find(x).remove()` is equivalent to `$(parent).remove(x)` so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes even if they are both jquery objects, they are not the same.

Comment: But they can be used the same way `$("div").first()[0] === $($($("div").first()))[0]` or `$("div").first().hide()` does exactly the same as `$($($("div").first())).hide()`

Comment: @freedomn-m Secondly writing `.remove('...')` is cleaner and follows the specs which is trying to facilitate things for us, instead of doing an additional `.find()` call.

Comment: Maybe, in your opinion, and that's fine, but it doesn't answer the question of why OPs code doesn't work.  I've not downvoted, just highlighted that this doesn't answer the question (IMO).

Comment: The OP isn't enough clear, but in my answer I provided alternatives and highlighted wrong things in the code. :) @freedomn-m Thank you for pointing this out

Comment: *First of all $($(this)) is different from $(this) so your code isn't working*....but in my answer, the code snippet works perfectly....

Comment: Any code snippet using OPs exact code as provided would work perfectly because OPs code works with the correct HTML.  They've not provided enough detail to provide a valid answer other than "your code works fine".   Providing alternatives is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code seems to be with an extra `$`. Try removing that extra `$`

```
$(this).find('.this_should_removed').remove();
```